# Nested dictionary with duplicate keys but different values

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm having a hard time returning the values of each instance of `$t` in the nested dictionary below.  What I need to do is pull each of the key-value pairs and add them individually to another dictionary.

Here's the JSON:

```
"breed": [
            {
                "$t": "Chihuahua"
            },
            {
                "$t": "Jack Russell Terrier"
            }
         ]
```

By the way, I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
>>> o = [ { "$t": "Chihuahua" }, { "$t": "Jack Russell Terrier" } ]
>>> [ item["$t"] for item in o ]
['Chihuahua', 'Jack Russell Terrier']
>>>
```

Comment: Tried something similar but I always seem to get an error 'TypeError: string indices must be integers' when I run it

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? (It depends I think on how you want to handle the multiple values corresponding to the same `$t`.)

```
nestedDict = { "breed": [
                        {
                         "$t": "Chihuahua"
                         },
                         {
                          "$t": "Jack Russell Terrier"
                          }
                         ]
              }

dictEntries = [ (k, v) for dicList in nestedDict.values() for d in dicList for (k, v) in d.items() ]

flattenedDict = { }
for k, v in dictEntries:
    flattenedDict.setdefault( k, [] ).append( v )

print ( flattenedDict )
```

This gives you:

```
{'$t': ['Chihuahua', 'Jack Russell Terrier']}
```

Comment: This works great with this example json but when I run it in the context of my application I'm getting an error of "'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'".  When I copy the output from a command line, an example of what I'm getting is: 'breeds': {u'$t': u'Domestic Short Hair'} So, the output is in unicode.  Any thoughts?  Thanks again.  I think I'm really close now!  BTW, when I loop through my application, the number of items output under breed is variable.  Not sure if this makes a difference.

Comment: Aha: so in this - `'breeds': {u'$t': u'Domestic Short Hair'}` - the value associated with 'breeds' is a single dictionary.  But in your original post, it's a list of dictionaries.  I think that's the difference rather than anything specific to unicode.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understood what are you trying to do. If you want to create a Python dict from JSON ans get its values with the "$t" key, here it is (if not, comment and I delete the answer).

```
# Many thanks to Dogbert, whose answer I copied the list comprehension from 
# (changing a few things), and many thanks to slothrop, whose answer gave me 
# ideas for my variable name. Not for those people, I would have used a silly 
# name like `thing` and would have used a for loop.
import json

nested_dict = json.loads('{"breed": [{"$t": "Chihuahua"}, '
                                    '{"$t": "Jack Russell Terrier"}]}')
[dic["$t"] for dic in nested_dict["breed"]]
```

If you need the key-value pairs of every dict inside your dict:

```
key_and_value_pairs = []
for dic in nested_dict["breed"]:
    key_and_value_pairs.extend(dic.items())
```